# Running Solr with Jetty

Tags: solr, jetty

I'm having a little trouble understanding how Solr fits in with Jetty, and why I can't seem to get the start.jar in the distribution package to work.

I can run all of the example configurations via `java -jar start.jar`. However, when I try to run something like the follwing --

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=/Users/jwwest/solr -jar $(brew --prefix solr)/libexec/example/start.jar
```

-- the following error occurs:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in start.config or command line.
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
```

I opened up the start.jar file, and there is a start.config file located inside of the jar which I'm assuming should handle this configuration for me. I'm not understanding why it will work when run from inside of the distribution examples directory, but not outside of it.

Comment: You hardly need to configure Jetty when running SOLR, all the configuration work is mostly done in your solr setup.  (solrconfig.xml). I you happen to work with ubuntu/debian, it's usually a matter of doing _apt-get install solr-jetty_ Then you need to define your schema for solr and create a core.   You would use the jetty init startup scripts to launch it.  I never touch start.jar

Answer (score 4):

You also need to define the `jetty.home` property. Try:

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=/Users/jwwest/solr -jar $(brew --prefix solr)/libexec/example/start.jar -Djetty.home=$(brew --prefix solr)/libexec/example
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see the effective command line start.jar generates by using the --dry-run command line flag.

> java -jar start.jar --dry-run

That will output everything with full path names so you can run it from outside the directory.

Source: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.0.M3/advanced-jetty-start.html

Answer (score 2):

The start.jar is a jetty specific mechanism that works to build out all the classpath requirements for starting up Jetty.  It is generally only used in the scope of the jetty distribution.  Pulling the start.jar out of the configuration and placing it somewhere else renders the default configuration of the start.config rather moot.

My understanding of Solr is that it bundles itself with a distribution of jetty, placing what it needs to run into the distribution and repackages it as its own.  They may have a custom start.config file that further adds its own locations for classpath resources and the like, or not.

The exception you are seeings stems from the start.config file expecting an etc/ directory containing jetty.xml formatted xml files which are used to configure the jetty process.

Jetty being often used in an embedded format has little to do with this issue, it is simply a common use case because jetty is incredibly easy to embed into an application.  Embedded instances of jetty rarely (if ever) leverage a start.jar...instead it is up to the embedding application to manage its own classpath.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change your folder where `start.jar` is located, then execute the same command.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is often used as embedded container. If you want to use the jetty, then a good start would be to copy the example directory and rename it to what you want it to be. The solr directory is the one for basic configuration.

Else it is recommended to use tomcat and the solr.war file.